# XML Deserialization when child element is different via abstract class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-parsing

I have a network call in my application based on input; i would get below 2 slightly different XML

XML 1:

```
<entry xml:base="https://www.w3.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"> 
      <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>                  
          <d:Ev_Message>201</d:Ev_Message>      
        </m:properties>
      </content>
    </entry>
```

XML 2:

```
<entry xml:base="https://www.w3.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"> 
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
            <licenses>
                <license>
                    <name>abcd</name>
                    <id>123</id>
                </license>
                <license>
                    <name>xyz</name>
                    <id>333</id>
                </license>
            </licenses>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

To deserialize above XML response into objects; i have constructed classes as shown:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "entry", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public class Entry
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "content", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public Content Content { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "content", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public class Content
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "properties", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata",
            Type = typeof(AType) )]
        public Properties Properties { get; set; } //Problem!
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(AType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(BType))]
    public abstract class Properties
    {
        
    }
        

    public class AType : Properties
    {
        [XmlElement("Ev_Message", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string Ev_Message{ get; set; }
    }

    public class BType : Properties
    {
        [XmlArray("licenses")]
        [XmlArrayItem("license")]
        public List<License> licenses { get; set; }
    }

    public class License
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Above structure deserializes XML 1 stream to AType properly. However, when i add XMLElement attribute for BType to Properties property in Content class for deserializing XML 2 structure; i get exception stating same element can not have duplicate name/namespace.

I am unable have both structure in place via abstract class for incoming different xml structure.

Kindly please help!

P.S:I have searched around stackoverflow for answers; no luck.

Thanks

Comment: When you have an inherited class in XML serialization there is a "type" attribute that is in the XML file.  You cannot deserialize the xml without the type attribute.  Put sample data into your classes and you will see the type.

Comment: If you see; i have added this line
[XmlElement(ElementName = "properties", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata",
            Type = typeof(AType) )]
But adding another same line but for BType would throw exception. So type wont help here.